# testing regular expression using junit?

Tags: java, regex, junit

I have written regular expression to ignore space:
the regular expression is

```
String ignore_regx = "[^\\s]";

Testcase:
public void TestClass {

@Test
public void testIgnoreRegx() {
 String input = " hai";
assertTrue(input.matches(ignore_regx));
 }
}
```

but above test is failing.

Could any body please how to test above expression using junit?

Comment: Side note: the expression is wrong. It should be `[^\\s]`

Comment: Or just this: `\\S+`

Comment: Write a JUnit test which uses various strings and asserts that a string  matches/doesn't match your regex (as appropriate).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik please look into my above test case.

Comment: You are done. Your JUnit test properly signaled that your regex is incorrect. Now fix the regex.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, since regx is already used in implementation. i could say regular expression is working.

Comment: If you already know it's working, then you don't need tests to confuse you :)

Comment: no its not like that, i have to write a testcase to ensure that it will be working always. i will get a problem if any body suddenly changes it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Theories to test multiple values.

```
@RunWith(Theories.class)
 public void TestClass {

  @DataPoints
  public static final String[] trueValues = new String[]{"", "blah", ...};

  @DataPoints
  public static final String[] falseValues = new String[]{"  ", " blah", "glah "};

 @Theory
 public void testIgnoreRegx_true(String input) {
    Assume.assumeThat(input, IsIn.isIn(trueValues));

   assertTrue(input.matches(ignore_regx));
 }

 @Theory
 public void testIgnoreRegx_false(String input) {
    Assume.assumeThat(input, IsIn.isIn(falseValues ));

   assertFalse(input.matches(ignore_regx));
 }
}
```

Comment: Very helpful, exactly what I was looking for